# Matlab 2D plot — display axis in binary

Tags: matlab, plot, binary, 2d, matlab-figure

I have a positive natural number vector which I am plotting in Matlab using the typical plot() function. Here is a sample plot:

[image: Plotting a natural number vector, axis in radix-10, need to display them in radix-2]

However, I need to see the vector (y axis) displayed in binary. Is there a way to change the axis display in binary (radix-2) ? I tried using dec2bin, but it only converts the integers to strings which can not be plotted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
L = get(gca,'YTickLabel');
set(gca,'YTickLabel',cellfun(@(x) dec2bin(str2num(x)),L,'UniformOutput',false));
```

**edit**: Since you wanted the ability to zoom, here is a way to make the axis zoomable:

```
zh = zoom(gcf);
set(zh,'ActionPreCallBack',@(source,event,s) set(gca,'YTickLabelMode','auto'))
set(zh,'ActionPostCallBack',@(source,event,s) set(gca,'YTickLabel',cellfun(@(x) dec2bin(str2num(x)),get(gca,'YTickLabel'),'UniformOutput',false)));
```

It resets the axis to decimal before the zoom and then converts back to binary after the zoom.

Comment: It works, but there is still an issue. It displays binary, but the wrong values. E.g. instead of displaying the point 766, it displays 750. Offset 16? However, at point 754 it displays 760. There appears to be some number-dependent offset.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Are you sure? It seems to work for me, here is an example where I show both: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSG6s.png

Comment: I realized it works only if you do not try to zoom. Once I zoom-in it goes wrong. Here is a sample figure: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5A_hdYOfvtLWGktbmJnRlowNjQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Of course, if you zoom it changes the YTicks. So you need to run the command again after every zoom. It is possible to automate this process using event handlers. I edited my solution. Hope it helps.